# What is the password of the user created in this Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to find out the password of the `jupyter` user created in this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/okuisatoshi/docker-ijavascript/blob/master/Dockerfile).

The user is created without a password but with the `-D` (defaults) flag:

```
RUN adduser -h /home/jupyter -D jupyter && \
    chown -R jupyter:jupyter /home/jupyter
USER jupyter
ENV HOME /home/jupyter
```

When I shell into the container and create a new user `jup1` with the same command, it's password is blank.

However, I can also confirm that the password of `jupyter` is NOT blank.

So what IS the password and where is it set?

#### /etc/passwd

```
jupyter:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/jupyter:
jup1:x:1001:1001:Linux User,,,:/home/jup1:
```

#### /etc/shadow

```
jupyter:!:17287:0:99999:7:::
jup1:!:18991:0:99999:7:::
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine

RUN apk update; apk upgrade; rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN apk --update add bash alpine-sdk zeromq-dev nodejs
RUN pip install jupyter
RUN npm install -g ijavascript

RUN adduser -h /home/jupyter -D jupyter && \
    chown -R jupyter:jupyter /home/jupyter
USER jupyter
ENV HOME /home/jupyter

RUN jupyter notebook --generate-config && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'" >> /home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False" >> /home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py && \
    echo "c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:37c14f4a2b90:0742999935c4297b7016ae0c31e2b16c3d919d52'" >> /home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
WORKDIR /home/jupyter/work
EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/ijs"]
```

Comment: did you look in /etc/shadow if there actually is something?

Comment: Sorry, just posted an update. Both users seem to be "locked" `!` - not sure what that means since I was able to `su jup1` and `whoami` showed `jup1`.

Comment: It probably doesn't have a password.  There's nothing you would do in a Docker container that would actually check it; if you're a host administrator with the ability to run `docker` commands, you can `docker run -u any-user` when you create the container.

Comment: My confusion is that when I am root I can `su jupyter` without a password and "become" jupyter. This makes me think the password is blank. But when I am jupyter I cannot `sudo ls` - it does not accept an empty password. So there is NO password - is this why `sudo` does not work from `jupyter`?

Comment: From root, you can su to any user, no password required. The account does not have a password set, which is not the same as having a blank password.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking for `jupyter` notbook password. But, according to the [README.md](https://github.com/okuisatoshi/docker-ijavascript#a-small-size-docker-container-running-jupyterijavascript) of the repository, it should be : `ijsuser`
"To invoke a server using a default password ("ijsuser")"

Comment: So how does one `sudo` from a user like jupyter which has no password? It prompts for one but doesn't accept empty.